# Calling solidity contract function

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have successfully compiled and published my contract in the rinkeby testnet with the remix browser compiler. Now I am struggling to call a function of my contract, either because my code is wrong or because it's published on rinkeby?

Can someone please provide me an example how to call this function using javascript and/or directly from the remix compiler:

```
function balanceOfTestCoin() returns (uint amount){
    for (uint i = 0; i < funders.length; i++){
        if(funders[i].addr == msg.sender){
            return funders[i].amountTestCoin;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Right now i am trying it this way:

```
<script>
 if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
     window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
 } else {
     console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
 }
 web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

 var abi = [{...}];
 var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
 var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0x....');
 console.log(myContractInstance);
 myContractInstance.balanceOfTestCoin(function(amount){ alert(amount) });

 //This doesnt work aswell: 
  alert("My TestCoins: " + myContractInstance.balanceOfTestCoin());
</script>
```

I am getting invalid address error on the line where I am trying to call the function.

Comment: The error message is exactly as described. Your `0x...` value is incorrect. You probably copied it wrong or copied the transaction hash instead. It should be a 40 length next string. Also, change your contract so the function is a `view` (it’s not changing any state).

Comment: Thanks for reply. The address is correct, i checked it again. But the address is only valid in rinkeby testnet maybe this is the fault? If yes how can i reach it then. And could you please explain what you mean with changing function to view? Thanks

Comment: how are you trying to access to this code? To connect to rinkeby just use metamask and, since you inject the provider correctly, you might be able to execute the code (changing the network metamask network to rinkeby). to change the status to view, just modify your method signature in this way function balanceOfTestCoin() public view returns (uint amount)

Comment: Looks like the problem was a missing public and maybe view identifier.